# Can PHP save to a file during __destruct()

Tags: php, destroy, file-put-contents

I would like to save some info to a file on my server using the `__destruct()` function in one of my classes.

However, every time I try to use `file_put_contents(...)` inside `__destruct()`, I get this error:

> Warning: file_put_contents(HTMLcache.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/time/HJ_Tag.php on line 141

`file_put_contents(...)` works just fine in other parts on my code, where it is called on the exact same file. What might it be causing this error during `__destruct()`, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Are you absolutely certain it's the _"exact same file"_? What file path are you using in either scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean `__destruct()` instead of `__destroy()`, so I edited your post.

> Can PHP save to a file during __destruct()

Yes, it can.
However, when you use relative filename with `file_put_contents()` like this:

```
file_put_contents('hello.txt', 'hello world');
```

The file may actually be created somewhere you're not expecting and you may not have write permission there,
which explains the error message.

In my case, it was created in `C:\Users\Rei\AppData\Local\VirtualStore`.
Which is odd because I never specified that directory.
I had to search my entire harddrive to find it.

To prevent that, always use absolute filename.
For instance, add `__DIR__` before the filename.

```
file_put_contents(__DIR__ . 'hello.txt', 'hello world');
```

And make sure you have write permission.

Comment: I'd say during garbage collection (when `__destruct()` would execute), the CWD changes

Comment: @Phil Yes, very likely. I read about that in an article.